# Outlook Email Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the mention code and it works all well with unique records, but the only problem is it sends multiple emails to 1 email id.

Email ID's are n column W (1st record is w6) and body of the mail is in column x6
have merge the body with code `"wsht.cells(i, 25) = sbody"`

any idea as who will this work were it wil send 1 email

for eg:- in w7 email id is xxx@gmail.com and in w10 email id is xxx@gmail.com
currently the code# send 2 mails, but it should send only 1 email to xxx@gmail.com

Any idea or update.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
  .EnableEvents = False
  .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim wSht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, lCuenta As Long
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
Dim sTo As String, sSbject As String, sBody As String

Set wSht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To LastRow
  lCuenta = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("W6:W" & i), Range("W" & i))
  If lCuenta = 1 Then
    ssubject = "PD Call Back"
    sTo = wSht.Cells(i, 1)
    sBody = wSht.Cells(i, 24)
    For k = i To LastRow
      If wSht.Cells(i, 1).Value = wSht.Cells(k + 1, 1).Value Then
        sBody = sBody & vbNewLine & wSht.Cells(k + 1, 24).Value
      End If
      wSht.Cells(i, 25) = sBody
    Next k
  End If

  Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

  On Error Resume Next
  With OutMail
    .To = sTo
    .Subject = ssubject
    .body = sBody
    .Send
  End With   
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Create a collection, array, or dictionary to store each email address as read by the code. If the email address doesn't already exist, then send the email. If the email address already exists, then do not send the (duplicate) email.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is occurring because you are testing whether or not this is the first time that the email id has been used and, if it isn't, you are resending the last email you set up.

The `End If` for your test needs to be moved after the section which sends the email:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, lCuenta As Long
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim sTo As String, sSbject As String, sBody As String

    Set wSht = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 6 To LastRow
        lCuenta = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("W6:W" & i), Range("W" & i))

        If lCuenta = 1 Then
            ssubject = "PD Call Back"
            sTo = wSht.Cells(i, 1)
            sBody = wSht.Cells(i, 24)

            For k = i To LastRow
                If wSht.Cells(i, 1).Value = wSht.Cells(k + 1, 1).Value Then
                    sBody = sBody & vbNewLine & wSht.Cells(k + 1, 24).Value
                End If
                wSht.Cells(i, 25) = sBody
            Next k

        'End If  '<-- Move this

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = sTo
                .Subject = ssubject
                .body = sBody
                .Send
            End With

        End If '<-- To here
    Next i
End Sub
```